# get URL parameter ActivatedRoute Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

In my application for me to know that there is a parameter in my navigation route, I need to configure this route.

I have a component that should not be rendered in `<router-outlet>`.

This component is a panel that is in the corner of the screen for sending and receiving messages.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'chatView/:contactId',
        component: ChatPanelComponent,
        resolve: {
            chat: ChatPanelService
        },
        canLoad: [GuardService],
    },
];
```

**This way render my component in the center of the screen and I do not want this to happen.**

In the module I configured so that when I accessed the route with `"chatView /: contactId"` I received a parameter to return the data of that contact when I loaded my application.

**In my component:**

```
    ngOnInit(): void {

        this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
            if (params.contactId){
               this._chatPanelService.getContato(params.contactId).then((contact) => {
                   this.toggleChat(contact);
               });
            }
        });
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way I can get this parameter without having to render this component in the `<router-outlet>` output, because this component is visible in the corner of the screen and thus renders the component twice in my application.

**I need a way to get a parameter without rendering the component in the center of the app-root screen.**

Comment: Just a guess... seems more like a design error rather then a routing problem. What is the problem you are really trying to solve? Maybe you click somewhere and the panel should load data / open ?

Comment: I have a component in the left corner of the screen which is the Messenger of my application ... When I run the route localhost: 4200 / chatView / contactId it should start the application with Messenger open.

Comment: This Messenger component loads inside HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume this all happens in component "Dashboard" (or whatever your parent component is named),
You would create 2 routes, both pointing to "DashboardComponent"

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    resolve: {
        chat: ChatPanelService
    },
    canLoad: [GuardService],
},
{
    path: 'dashboard/:contactId',
    component: DashboardComponent,
    resolve: {
        chat: ChatPanelService
    },
    canLoad: [GuardService],
},
];
```

Then you would use your

```
this._activatedRoute.params.subscribe
```

code to read the contact id param